A box has 6 black, 4 red, 2 white, and 3 blue shirts. What is the probability of picking 2 red shirts and 1 blue shirt?
The correct answer is $\frac{18}{455}$ but I am unsure why my approach is incorrect. It goes as such:
There are $\binom{3}{2} = 3$ ways of choosing where the red shirt goes in the three picks. Then there are $\frac{4\times3}{2}$ ways to pick the red shirts such that order doesn't matter. Then there are $3$ choices for the blue shirt. There are $\binom{15}{3}$ ways to pick $3$ shirts from $15$ shirts. So there is a $$\dfrac{3 \times 6 \times 3}{455} = \dfrac{54}{455}$$ probability of picking two red shrits and one blue shirts. Why is my answer off by a factor of $3$?

The probability is $1$, if you're allowed to look at the shirts and you want to pick two red ones and a blue one.

When you multiply by $\binom 32 = 3$, you're counting the number of ways to pick the shirts in which the position of the blue shirt (first, second, or third) matters.  But when you use $\binom {15}{3}=455$ as your denominator, you're counting the number of ways to pick shirts where order doesn't matter.  That's why you're off by a factor of $3$.

You wish to obtain $\it 2$ from $\it 4$ red shirts and $\it 1$ from $\it 3$ blue shirts, when selecting $\it 3$ from all $\it 15$ shirts.
You do not need to account for order of selection in either numerator or denominator, since:
$$\require{enclose}\dbinom {15}3={~~~~\dbinom40\dbinom 30\dbinom 83\\+\dbinom40\dbinom 31\dbinom 82+\dbinom41\dbinom 30\dbinom 82\\+\dbinom40\dbinom 32\dbinom 81+\dbinom41\dbinom 31\dbinom 81+\dbinom42\dbinom 30\dbinom 81\\+\dbinom40\dbinom 33\dbinom 80+\dbinom41\dbinom 32\dbinom 80+\color{red}{\enclose{box}{\color{black}{\dbinom42\dbinom 31\dbinom 80}}}+\dbinom43\dbinom 30\dbinom 80}$$
